# Word Add-In: Add submenu to CommandBar

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, add-in

I am trying to add a submenu to the CommandBar in Word application.

I managed to create a menuitem, in the right click menu, that fires an event. What I want for is a new submenu to appear.

This is an example of what I am looking for:

[image]

The code below is part of what I have written.

```
application.CustomizationContext = 
Office.CommandBar commandBar = application.CommandBars["Text"];
Office.CommandBarButton button =commandBar.Controls.Add(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton) as Office.CommandBarButton;
button.accName = "Accronym Highlights";
button.Caption = "Accronym Highlights";
button.Tag = "UNIQUE";
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What you are looking for is a cascading submenu. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165707.aspx